# Get size of std::array without an instance

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

Given this struct:

```
struct Foo {
  std::array<int, 8> bar;
};
```

How can I get the number of elements of the `bar` array if I don't have an instance of `Foo`?

Comment: how about using a macro instead of hardcoding the array size?

Comment: `sizeof(Foo::bar);`?

Comment: @WebertS.Lima - Perish the thought. Not a macro.

Comment: `sizeof(Foo::bar)` returns the size in bytes instead of the number of elements. I'll make the question clearer.

Comment: @StoryTeller before editing the question I thought he wanted to get the array max size, not current size.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima - and is different for an `std::array`?

Comment: @WebertS.Lima - `std::array` is a fixed size container. It's the same. My problem with your suggestion is not the elimination of a magic number (which is excellent), but the use of a macro to do it.

Comment: @StoryTeller right but what he wants is to count how many elements are there in the array at some point. That's what I mean by it's "current size" vs the max size.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima - `std::array` doesn't shrink or grow. It will always be 8 constructed objects.

Comment: Well, there is `Foo().bar.size()`  . Q would be more interesting if Foo had no default constructor

Comment: @StoryTeller I think I misunderstood the question. Sorry and thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima - current size vs max size is a problem for variable size containers (maps, vectors, sets, etc.) but `std::array` has a fixed size.

Comment: @max66 I see, but AFAIK I thought you could declare a std:array of size 8 and put 4 elements in it, couldn't you? That's what I was thinking about.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima - No; if you declare a `std::array<int, 8>` you ever have a container with 8 elements; you can set the value of 4 of this elements (after the initialization) but the other 4 are present with initial value

Comment: @max66 Oh I see. Now I get it perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima - maybe you're thinking about `std::vector<int>` where you can `reserve()` the size for 8 elements and put only 4 in it.

Comment: @max66 I was misinterpreting how std::array works behind.

Comment: Also, the array doesn't exist yet, I sure hope it's not half-full.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You may use [`std::tuple_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size):

```
std::tuple_size<decltype(Foo::bar)>::value
```

Comment: Hooking this here: the various classes and functions dealing with `std::tuple`s (`std::tuple_size`, `std::tuple_element`, `std::get`) have handy specializations to treat an `std::array<T, N>` like a `std::tuple<T, T, ..., T>`.

Comment: Can be simplified in C++17 to `std::tuple_size_v<decltype(Foo::bar)>`

Answer (score 31):

Despite the [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41345296/4987285) of @Jarod42, here is another possible solution based on `decltype` that doesn't use `tuple_size`.
It follows a minimal, working example that works in C++11:

```
#include<array>

struct Foo {
    std::array<int, 8> bar;
};

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t N = decltype(Foo::bar){}.size();
    static_assert(N == 8, "!");
}
```

`std::array` already has a constexpr member function named `size` that returns the value you are looking for.

Comment: so this has the same issue as @waxrat's answer below, it requires construction even if that construction **may** be `constexpr`, in that sense `std::tuple_size` is a better answer because it doesn't require any construction or destruction in the non-`constexpr` case.

Comment: @Mgetz I didn't say it's better. :-) ... Different solutions and answers can help future readers, no matter if they are the accepted ones or not.

Comment: hence my comment, I sought to ensure such readers would understand why `std::tuple_size` is a better choice. That said I'd probably do a `using array_size = std::tuple_size` for readability.

Comment: @Mgetz Names aren't the strongest feature of the language, I agree. We are dealing with a language that contains a function named `std::move` that doesn't move anything. What else? :-) (note: just joking)

Comment: This answer has the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345182/get-size-of-stdarray-without-an-instance#comment69892592_41345330) as another answer ("won't work for classes without a default constructor") Also, (for non-trivial types) it will execute the constructor  N times (potentially with side effect).

Answer (score 6):

You could give `Foo` a `public static constexpr` member.

```
struct Foo {
 static constexpr std::size_t bar_size = 8;
 std::array<int, bar_size> bar;
}
```

Now you know the size of bar from `Foo::bar_size` and you have the added flexibility of naming `bar_size` to something more descriptive if `Foo` ever has multiple arrays of the same size.

Comment: Given the other answers showing this is possible to do without the `static const`, I don't find this a good answer.

Comment: @Tas: To my mind, the issue is that this answer gets things backwards: instead of answering the question of how to get some existing array's number of elements, it says to declare a known number and alter the array's declaration to template it on that. So, the `static constexpr` member is really not the thing to complain about; it'll consume no space in instances and be completely optimised away in its translation unit (unless its address is taken, but then that would require an out-of-line definition, so).

Comment: @Tas @underscore_d Thanks. The reason I made this answer is because the high scoring answers were complicated. The size of bar without the `static constexpr` is a magic number. This solution removes the magic number and solves the problem with one simple line.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it the same as for legacy arrays:

```
sizeof(Foo::bar) / sizeof(Foo::bar[0])
```

Comment: or use the much more readable [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) but this isn't an answer as this would still require constructing an instance.

Comment: A few other things to keep in mind `sizeof std::array<int, 4>` may not equal `sizeof int[4]` that's an implementation detail. Moreover if you're going to construct the [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) then just use the [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) member

Comment: I meant `sizeof(Foo::bar) / sizeof(Foo::bar[0])`. No instance of Foo needed.

Comment: @Mgetz Don't other, overt requirements of `std::array` mean that it must have the same size and layout as a raw array in reality, even if that's not explicitly required?

Comment: @underscore_d realistically yes, but it's still implementation dependent. As such I wouldn't trust it, there are too many things a compiler can do to mess this up and `std::array` has a `size()` member anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sizeof(Foo::bar) / sizeof(int)
```

Comment: I tried and I am getting the same value for both. `#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
  std::array<int, 8> bar;
};

int main()
{
   cout << sizeof(Foo::bar) / sizeof(int) << endl;
   cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(Foo::bar)>::value << endl;
   return 0;
}`

Answer (score -4):

You can use like:

```
sizeof Foo().bar
```

Comment: See [this comment from OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345182/get-size-of-stdarray-without-an-instance#comment69892397_41345182): he's after the number of elements, not the total size.

Comment: @Happy - the OP modified the answer: he want the number of elements in the array (8 in the example), not the `sizeof`

Comment: note: won't work for classes without a default constructor

Comment: @M.M Since `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand, you could always just `std::declval<Foo>()`.

Comment: @M.M [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e578836e8388974) works for me (revised version with deleted default ctor).

Comment: @Angew technically `std::array` is allowed to have padding

Comment: @M.M OK, but ... ouch. I don't thik people would be too happy about a `std::array` implementation which *did* have padding. But you do have a point.